# declaring key in IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

my goal is retrieve value of counter which was stored last time when application closed.
i.e. i am storing the counter value in isolated storage. if counter has value 5 and application is closed and again started i should be able to retrieve 5.
for this purpose i have written following code but i cannot make out of it.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings isoStoreSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
int count=0;
isoStoreSettings["flag"];
if (isoStoreSettings["flag"]!="set")
{                
   isoStoreSettings["count"] = count;
   isoStoreSettings["flag"] = "set";
}


count = isoStorageSettings["count"];  //using the value of count stored previously

//some code which updates the count variable

isoStorageSettings["count"]=count;
```

the problem with this code is that declaration of key in isolatedstorage is now allowed, we must assign some value to that key
but if i assign value to that key, it will reinitialize the key each time application is started.
so, if anyone can solve this, please help
even there is any other alternative to isolatedstorage for my goal then also please share.

Comment: Where are you using this code? What is the flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load your `count` every time the App is Launched then put your code in `Application_Launching` event in App.xaml.cs:

```
// declare static variable which you will be able to access from anywhere
public static int count;

private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains("count")) count = (int)settings["count"];
    else count = 0;
}
```

On Clising event - save your variable:

```
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains("count")) settings["count"] = count;
    else settings.Add("count", count);
    settings.Save();
}
```

From anywhere in your code, you should be able to access your variable like this:

```
int myVariable = App.count;
App.count++; 
// and so on
```

Note that you may also think about `Activated` and `Deactivated` events - for more information read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

I also don't know what `flag` suppose to do, but code above should save your variable just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use updated count value in Add method like below:

```
    IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStorageSettingsCount = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if (isolatedStorageSettingsCount.Contains("count"))
            {
                isolatedStorageSettingsCount.Remove("count");
                isolatedStorageSettingsCount.Add("count",5);
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                isolatedStorageSettingsCount.Add("count",5);
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            }
```

To retrive your count value use below code:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStorageSettingsCount = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
string strCount = (string)isolatedStorageSettingsCount["count"];
int count=Convert.ToInt32(strCount);
```

Comment: use this you would really find it helpful

Comment: this code also has the same problem,
what should i do for very first assignment of count ? 
i have to initialize it with zero, but if i do so then it will reinitialize it every time.

Comment: when it reinitialize what value you are getting